# PHP Building faster Loops - Calculate blending ratios

Tags: php, performance, loops, calculator, blending

I want to calculate blending ratios. Three components m1 30%, m2 30%, m3 40%
with a variation of 5%

```
<?php
    $beginn = microtime(true);
    $loops = 0;
    $hits = 0;
    $precision = 1;
    $focus = 5;

    print("<table border=1 cellpadding=2>");

    for($m1 = 30 - $focus;  $m1 <= 30 + $focus; $m1 += $precision) {
    for($m2 = 30 - $focus;  $m2 <= 30 + $focus; $m2 += $precision) {
    for($m3 = 40 - $focus;  $m3 <= 40 + $focus; $m3 += $precision) {

        $loops++;

        if (($m1 + $m2 + $m3) == 100) {
            $hits++;

            print("<tr>");
            print("<td>" . $m1 . " %</td>");
            print("<td>" . $m2 . " %</td>");
            print("<td>" . $m3 . " %</td>");
            print("<td>" . ($m1 + $m2 + $m3) . " %</td>");
            print("</tr>");

        }

    }
    }
    }
    print("</table>");

    print(" Loops: " . $loops);
    print(" Hits: " . $hits);

    $dauer = microtime(true) - $beginn;
    echo " $dauer Sek.";
?>
```

The problem is, I need 1331 loops to find 91 hits (in sum 100%), 
looking like this

```html
<table border=1 cellpadding=2><tr><td>25 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>25 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>25 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>25 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>25 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>25 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>26 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>27 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>28 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>29 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>45 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>30 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>44 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>31 %</td><td>34 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>43 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>32 %</td><td>33 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>42 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>33 %</td><td>32 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>41 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>34 %</td><td>31 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>25 %</td><td>40 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>26 %</td><td>39 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>27 %</td><td>38 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>28 %</td><td>37 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>29 %</td><td>36 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr><tr><td>35 %</td><td>30 %</td><td>35 %</td><td>100 %</td></tr></table>
```

I would like to caculate the 91 hits directly, so the loops will be 14 times
faster :)

Comment: Whenever you see a tripple nested loop, odds are you're not going about your business in the most efficient way. That's for sure, but given that this code actually _works_, and you're looking for advice on how to improve it, do consider posting it on [the codereview site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: For starters, though: `$m1` and `$m2` are equal value ranges, that you can compute like so: `range(30-$focus, 30+$focus, $precision);`. Same goes for the inner loop, but all that does is solving a simple equasion (_100 - (m1 + m2) = x_), surely you don't need a loop for that. Create the range array, use `array_map` or `array_filter`, and then subtract the rest of the values from 100 to get the m3 values

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the bounds for m2 that will yield an acceptable value for m3.

For example when m1 = 25, since the maximum value for m3 is 45, m2 cannot have a value *below* 30, otherwise 25+29 would leave 46, which is unacceptable for m3 (range 35...45).

This means that the lower bound for m2 is 100 - m1 - (max of m3). But this only holds if the value thus obtained is *higher* than the lower acceptable bound for m2: if the calculation had yielded 24 instead of 30, we would have had to start with a value of 25 for m2, since 24 is not acceptable.

So we want the maximum between (the minimum acceptable value of m2) and (the value assumed by m2 when m3 is at *its* maximum).

The same reasoning for the upper limit yields m2max = min(m2limit, 100 - (m3min)) .

```
$focus = 5;
$precision = 1;
$loops = 0;

for ($m1 = 30 - $focus; $m1 <= 30 + $focus; $m1 += $precision) {
    $m2a = 100 - $m1 - (40 + $focus); // This is the minimum m2 that makes sense.
    $m2a = max($m2a, 30 - $focus);  // But it must also be allowed by m2 bounds.

    $m2b = 100 - $m1 - (40 - $focus); // Maximum m2 that makes sense.
    $m2b = min($m2b, 30 + $focus); // Clip to the allowed range.

    for ($m2 = $m2a; $m2 <= $m2b; $m2 += $precision) {
        $loops++;
        $m3 = 100 - $m1 - $m2;
        print "{$m1}% + {$m2}% + {$m3}% = " . ($m1 + $m2 + $m3) . "%\n";
    }
}
print $loops . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
25% + 30% + 45% = 100%
...omitted...
35% + 30% + 35% = 100%

91
```

To go even faster - not that it makes sense - you can optimize the output:

```
for ($m1 = 30 - $focus; $m1 <= 30 + $focus; $m1 += $precision) {
    $m2a = 100 - $m1 - (40 + $focus); // This is the minimum m2 that makes sense.
    $m2a = max($m2a, 30 - $focus);  // But it must also be allowed by m2 bounds.

    $m2b = 100 - $m1 - (40 - $focus); // Maximum m2 that makes sense.
    $m2b = min($m2b, 30 + $focus); // Clip to the allowed range.

    $tr = '<tr><td>' . $m1 . ' %</td><td>';

    for ($m2 = $m2a; $m2 <= $m2b; $m2 += $precision) {
        $m3 = 100 - $m1 - $m2;
        // We know that m1 + m2 + m3 = 100.
        $html .= $tr . $m2 . ' %</td><td> 100%</td></tr>';
    }
}
print $html;
```

Comment: Great. Thank you! Very happy

Answer (score 0):

Here's the first optimization that comes to mind ...

```
for($m1 = 30 - $focus;  $m1 <= 30 + $focus; $m1 += $precision) {
    for($m2 = 30 - $focus;  $m2 <= 30 + $focus; $m2 += $precision) {
        $loops++;
        $m3 = 100 - $m1 - $m2;
        if ($m3>=40-$focus && $m3<=40+$focus) {
            // a hit! so print stuff
        }
    }
}
```

This eliminates the innermost loop, for $m3, since the necessary value of $m3 can be calculated from $m1 and $m2.

EDIT:  I just tried it. Eliminating inner loop drops $loops from 1331 to 121.  Is that close enough to 91?  Any further optimizations to get closer to 91 will likely cost a lot in terms of code incomprehensibility.